# SQL Multiple Lookups from Join

Tags: sql

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT cu.CustomerCountryID,
       pr.ProviderCountryID,
       po.ProductCountryID
FROM   tblCustomer cu
       INNER JOIN tblProvider pr
         ON cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
       INNER JOIN tblProduct po
         ON pr.ProdID = po.ProdID
```

There is then a fourth table that contains the name of the country. I want to replace the CountryID with the CountryName.

I can't think right now how to do it without resulting to subqueries

Can anyone advise on a faster way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by joining to the country table multiple times:

```
SELECT cust_country.CountryName,
   prov_country.CountryName,
   prod_country.CountryName
FROM   tblCustomer cu
   INNER JOIN tblProvider pr
     ON cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
   INNER JOIN tblProduct po
     ON pr.ProdID = po.ProdID 
   INNER JOIN tblCountry cust_country
     ON cu.CustomerCountryID = cust_country.CountryID
   INNER JOIN tblCountry prov_country
     ON pr.CustomerCountryID = prov_country.CountryID
   INNER JOIN tblCountry prod_country
     ON co.CustomerCountryID = prod_country.CountryID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    cco.CountryName as CustomerCountryName, pco.CountryName as ProviderCountryName, ppco.CountryName as ProductCountryName
FROM
    tblCustomer cu
INNER JOIN
    tblProvider pr ON cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
INNER JOIN
    tblProduct po ON pr.ProdID = po.ProdID
INNER JOIN
    tblCountry cco ON cu.CustomerCountryID = cco.CountryID
INNER JOIN
    tblCountry pco ON pr.ProviderCountryID = pco.CountryID
INNER JOIN
    tblCountry ppco ON po.ProductCountryID = ppco.CountryID
```

This assumes you have a table called `tblCountry` with a `CountryID` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the country table multiple times:

```
SELECT cuco.CountryName,
       prco.CountryName,
       poco.CountryName
FROM   tblCustomer cu
       INNER JOIN tblProvider pr
         ON cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
       INNER JOIN tblProduct po
         ON pr.ProdID = po.ProdID 
       INNER JOIN tblCountry cuco
         ON cu.CustomerCountryID = co.CountryID
       INNER JOIN tblCountry prco
         ON pr.ProviderCountryID = co.CountryID
       INNER JOIN tblCountry poco
         ON po.ProductCountryID = co.CountryID
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of join to get the value, there is no other way. It doesn't have to be the same kind of join as the two you are already doing, though; it could be an inline view:

```
SELECT cu.CustomerCountryID,
       pr.ProviderCountryID,
       po.CountryName
FROM   tblCustomer cu
,      tblProvider pr
,     (SELECT po.ProdID
       ,      co.CountryName
       FROM   tblProduct po
       ,      tblCountry co
       WHERE  po.ProductCountryID = co.productCountryID
) po
WHERE  cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
AND    pr.ProdID = po.ProdID;
```

Alternatively (and depending on the DB provider) you can have a sub-select in the select list:

```
SELECT cu.CustomerCountryID,
       pr.ProviderCountryID,
       (SELECT co.CountryName FROM tblCountry co WHERE po.ProductCountryID = co.productCountryID) AS CountryName
FROM   tblCustomer cu
,      tblProvider pr
,      tblProduct po
WHERE  cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
AND    pr.ProdID = po.ProdID;
```

I have shown the example for one of the tables only but the same can be applied to all three.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a join for each name of ID... Also you can try this;

```
SELECT 
  (Select CountryName from tblCountry where CountryID =cu.CustomerCountryID),
  (Select CountryName from tblCountry where CountryID =pr.ProviderCountryID),
  (Select CountryName from tblCountry where CountryID =po.ProductCountryID)                
FROM tblCustomer cu    
  INNER JOIN tblProvider pr ON cu.ProvID = pr.ProvID
  INNER JOIN tblProduct po ON pr.ProdID = po.ProdID
```